# How to remove back button from scrollview in Xcode/Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview

I am trying to remove the automatically generated back button from my scrollview in Xcode. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using an `UINavigationController` , the `UIScrollView` not have any `UINavigationBar` inside it. You need to set a normal `UIViewController` or hide the back button in your `UINavigationBar` in the following way:

```
 self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:true)
```

Or in this way :

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: navigationController, action: nil)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

I hope this help you.